# empty target selection window on STM32CubeIDE

Tags: eclipse-cdt, stm32, fedora, stm32cubeide

STM32CubeIDE is running on Fedora 32. To launch the code on the target board, I opened STM32Project -> Target selection.

But the window (Target Selection) is empty and there is no chance to select any boards.
Any suggestions to figure out this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort this out on my Fedora 32 install by adding a line to my /usr/share/applications/st-stm32cubeide-1.3.0.desktop file.

Exec=/usr/bin/env GDK_BACKEND=x11 export GDK_BACKEND

above the existing Exec line in the aforementioned .desktop file

Comment: This worked for me! My Exec line is: `Exec=/usr/bin/env GDK_BACKEND=x11 /opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.4.0/stm32cubeide %F`